# ng-href link not followed on Firefox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I'm using ng-href which seems to produce the correct results, and the correct behaviour on Chrome but not on Firefox.

on the page www.mydomian.com/clubs/ in my rails app i have the Haml

`%a{'ng-href' => '\players\{{player.id}}'} {{player.name}}`

when run this produces this html

```
<a ng-href="\players\14208" class="ng-binding" href="\players\14208">Dylan Robertson</a>
```

when I use Chrome and click on this link I'm taken to

```
 www.mydomian.com/players/14208
```

however on firefox when I click on this same link I'm taken to

```
www.mydomian.com/clubs/%5Cplayers%5C14208
```

I can't work out why anyone any ideas?
I have 
 $rootElement.off('click') set in my app.run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your slashes to go the other way;

```
  <a ng-href="/players/14208" class="ng-binding" href="/players/14208">Dylan Robertson</a>
```

Comment: Argh, that fixed it, how come it worked on Chrome which is what threw me